# How can I override the video Play button in a Web page?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-webview, html5-video, embed

I'm working on an Android e-mail app that will be able to embed videos in a WebView contained in the message content before sending the message to the recipients. To keep the size of the message down, I don't embed the actual video in the content: instead, I'll stream the video to the user when the Play button is pressed. So, my question is, how do I override the Play button, so I can start the streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all I need to do is add some Javascript to the message and use onClick() on the Play button to point to the code.